# Privileges on Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, executable

In Linux, I had created a userid. After creating this, I encountered a problem that the .EXE Files are not opened on simple click. They seem to be not privileged for my user account.

How can I overcome from this?

Comment: `.exe` files are usually Microsoft PE/COFF executables, which are not supported natively under Linux. Why do you think this is a permissions issue rather than the fact that Linux does not support this ABI?

Comment: If you are in fact trying to use Microsoft Window's .exe files they won't work on Linux.

Comment: @ChrisDown Not necessarily true. I've seen some third party apps give their (Linux) executables the `.exe` extension.

Comment: @JosephR. I have also seen this, which is why I said "usually".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these `.exe`files were actually compiled for Linux (and your specific architecture) you need to ensure they have execute permissions:

```
chmod +x your_file_names_here
```

To make sure these files are actually meant to run on Linux, check the output of

```
file one_file_name_here
```

Answer (score 2):

- If you're really talking about files with ending .exe => These are most probably windows executables, not linux.
- If you're talking about executable files (executable bits set in permission => To see this, open the properties dialog in the file manager or do a 'ls -l' in the shell), there are the foloowing 2 effects that might prevent execution:

  - Excutable bit only set for user or group and you're not the user and not in the group: Confirm with 'ls -l' again or the properties dialog.
  - noexec mount option set on the file system. Check by running mount (w/o any arguments). You would get something like

    /dev/sda5 on /your-file-system type ext2 (rw, noexec)

    This would be most unusual, though (and also confusing, because the executables bits would be there)

I assume you're actually trying to run windows executables and enumerated the other possibilities only for sake of completeness. This should be possible with Wine (a windows emulator for linux) but wine needs to be installed first.